# Why is $MyInvocation.ScriptName not set and string comparisons?

Tags: powershell, duck-typing

This began as an effort to have all four (4) of the PowerShell profile scripts identify themselves and their location.

`$MyInvocation.ScriptName` was suggested for getting the script name, but I have yet to see it be anything other than an empty string. No, not $null, empty (''). This seems counter to many suggestions here on SO.

My first assumption was that `$MyInvocation.ScriptName` was `$null`, but that is not the case. To my surprise however, it is considered to be -lt 0. What is the rationale for comparing a String to an Int32?

I did find `$MyInvocation.InvocationName` which appears to give the script name, but not a directory path to it.

```
PS C:\Users\lit\Documents\PowerShell> Get-Content .\profile.ps1
Write-Host "Current User, All Hosts @ $(Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)\$(Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
Write-Host "`$MyInvocation.ScriptName is $MyInvocation.ScriptName"
Write-Host "`$MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq `$null results in $($MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq $null)"
Write-Host "`$($MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq 0) results in $($MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq 0)"
Write-Host "`$($MyInvocation.ScriptName -lt 0) results in $($MyInvocation.ScriptName -lt 0)"
Write-Host "`$($MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq '') results in $($MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq '')"

Try { '' -eq 0 }
Catch { Write-Host "Caught -lt 0" }

Write-Host $MyInvocation.InvocationName

PS C:\Users\lit\Documents\PowerShell> .\profile.ps1
Current User, All Hosts @ C:\Users\lit\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1
$MyInvocation.ScriptName is System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo.ScriptName
$MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq $null results in False
$(System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo.ScriptName -eq 0) results in False
$(System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo.ScriptName -lt 0) results in True
$(System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo.ScriptName -eq '') results in True
False
.\profile.ps1
```

Suggestion from JosefZ works.

```
PS C:\src\my-powershell> type .\gname.ps1
Write-Host "`$MyInvocation.InvocationName is $((Resolve-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName).Path)"
Write-Host (Resolve-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName).Path

PS C:\src\my-powershell> .\gname.ps1
$MyInvocation.InvocationName is C:\src\my-powershell\gname.ps1
C:\src\my-powershell\gname.ps1
```

I have tried to collect these possible answers, but still only one or two deliver what is needed. $MyInvocation.Command is always $null and $MyInvocation.ScriptName is always and empty string ('').

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-Content callme.ps1
"=== These two give the full path and invocation path"
Write-Host "$(Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)\$(Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
Write-Host "`$(`$MyInvocation.InvocationName) is $($MyInvocation.InvocationName)"
"=== `$MyInvocation.Command is `$null, but it, and its Source member, do have a type"
Write-Host "`$MyInvocation.Command -eq `$null is $($MyInvocation.Command -eq $null)"
Write-Host "`$MyInvocation.Command is $MyInvocation.Command"
Write-Host "`$(`$MyInvocation.Command) is $($MyInvocation.Command)"
Write-Host "`$MyInvocation.Command.Source is $MyInvocation.Command.Source"
Write-Host "`$(`$MyInvocation.Command.Source) is $($MyInvocation.Command.Source)"
"==="
Write-Host "`$MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq `$null is $($MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq $null)"
Write-Host "`$MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq '' is $($MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq '')"
Write-Host "`$MyInvocation.ScriptName is $MyInvocation.ScriptName"
Write-Host "`$(`$MyInvocation.ScriptName) is $($MyInvocation.ScriptName)"

PS C:\src\t> .\callme.ps1
=== These two give the full path and invocation path
C:\src\t\callme.ps1
$($MyInvocation.InvocationName) is .\callme.ps1
=== $MyInvocation.Command is $null, but it, and its Source member, do have a type
$MyInvocation.Command -eq $null is True
$MyInvocation.Command is System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo.Command
$($MyInvocation.Command) is
$MyInvocation.Command.Source is System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo.Command.Source
$($MyInvocation.Command.Source) is
===
$MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq $null is False
$MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq '' is True
$MyInvocation.ScriptName is System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo.ScriptName
$($MyInvocation.ScriptName) is
```

Comment: I would go for `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source` as a more reliable alternative

Comment: `Write-Host "\`$MyInvocation.InvocationName is $((Resolve-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName).Path)"` and  another line `Write-Host  (Resolve-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName).Path`

Comment: @JosefZ - That appears to give the directory from which the PowerShell executable was started. I am looking to get the current script's location.

Comment: `$MyInvocation.ScriptName` is script name, which invoke current command.

Comment: @lit tested using `PowerShell  -version 2.0` as well as using current PS version (´5.0´) on `Win_8.1(64 bit)`.

Comment: @JosefZ - Not sure what I was looking at, but a script shows that it works. I still want to know more about comparing a String to an Int32.

Comment: `'$MyInvocation.ScriptName', '& { $MyInvocation.ScriptName }' | sc .\script2.ps1; '.\script2.ps1' | sc .\script1.ps1; .\script1.ps1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have a bug on line 2 of your script. You probably want to wrap `$MyInvocation.ScriptName` in `$(...)`:

```
Write-Host "`$MyInvocation.ScriptName is $($MyInvocation.ScriptName)"
```

Next, the `try{}catch{}` will only work if the expression in the `try{}` block throws an exception. A simple comparison doesn't do that. If you were expecting PowerShell to complain that you are comparing try different types then... it doesn't. See below.

The comment from @PetSerAl is pertinent. When you run the profile from the PowerShell prompt, the **ScriptName** is what calls the current command. If you were to call your profile script from *another* script, you'd see the calling script name. I think you might want to look at the `$MyInvocation.MyCommand` property instead, as per Matthias' suggestion.

And finally...

When you compare a string with a number in the way you are doing, PowerShell "protects" you and automatically treats the second entity (the number) as a string and you're left with a string comparison: is the empty string `""` *less than* the string `"0"`? Why, yes it is. It is also less than `"-9999"`:

```
[PS]> "" -lt -9999
True
```

So `-9999` is bigger than nothing? Lets switch them around to check, and we see the same principle at work:

```
[PS]> -9999 -gt ""
False
```

Seemingly a contradiction unless you remember that in each case the element on the right-hand-side of the comparison is being treated as a string or int depending on what the left-hand-side is.